# How to start and stop celery beat and workers in Django?

Tags: python, django, celery, periodic-task

I'm getting some data from an API every 30 seconds and insert to mongoDB periodically. hence, I used celery to process it in the background. celery.py as follow:

```
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    from example.tasks import API
    sender.add_periodic_task(30, API.s(), name='Api')
```

I have tasks.py as follow:

```
@shared_task
def API():
    data=request.get(url).json()
    db.collectionName.insert_many(data)
```

Then, I used two commands to run the task in the background periodically:

```
celery -A DjangoCelery1 beat -l info
celery -A DjangoCelery1 worker -l info
```

Everything all right and data is getting from the API and saved in MongoDB.
Now, I want to able to start and stop all running tasks by press a button on a web page.

What should I do for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my answer on this page:
https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/#reader-comments

Comment: Private page, cant read